# Monitor AWS S3 Replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, monitoring, replication, amazon-cloudwatch

I have cross-region S3 replication on, and I want to follow a testing or monitoring procedure, in which I can get regular updates or status checks that the replication is working.
I am not sure how to exactly do that. There are not even any CloudWatch metrics for S3 replication and no proper AWS solution.

- Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with replication metrics and S3 event notifications. This will give you a minute-by-minute view and you can attach it to SNS to notify you of the status in case of failures.

Read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-metrics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution "Cross-Region Replication Monitor" provided by AWS. Here is the guide how to implement this solution
https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/cross-region-replication-monitor/

Answer (score 0):

Create an event notification for whenever an object is created (or under a prefix) and invoke a lambda A which creates an eventbridge rule ...that keeps invoke lambda B every 15 mins.
with obj name and object version payload.

In the second lambda poll below s3 api.
aws s3api head-object --bucket source-bucket --key object-key --version-id object-version-id    and check for replication staus of the object/s . If status == failed/completed update sns/sqs/dynamo and delete the eventbridge rule else if status is pending do nothing.

Comment: Please do make use of proper text formatting.